# How can i convert Mongodb cursor result to Dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mongodb, dataframe

This is my code:

```
x = list(coll.find({"activities.flowCenterInfo": {
            '$exists': True
        }},{'activities.activityId':1,'activities.flowCenterInfo':1,'_id':0}).limit(5))

for row in x:
    print(row)
```

This is the result of x for one sample:

```
{'activities': [{'activityId': 'B83F36898FE444309757FBEB6DF0685D', 'flowCenterInfo': {'processId': '178888', 'demandComplaintSubject': 'İkna Görüşmesi', 'demandComplaintDetailSubject': 'Hayat Sigortadan Ayrılma', 'demandComplaintId': '178888'}}]}
```

I want to convert to Dataframe to write the oracle table. How can i convert it to Dataframe properly i can't find anyway

[This image shows that the mongodb structure of one sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2yM2.png)

Comment: what the `x` contents?

Comment: I shared the x in the question   one sample is below i want to convert this to Dataframe                                                                                                            {'activities': [{'activityId': 'B83F36898FE444309757FBEB6DF0685D', 'flowCenterInfo': {'processId': '178888', 'demandComplaintSubject': 'İkna Görüşmesi', 'demandComplaintDetailSubject': 'Hayat Sigortadan Ayrılma', 'demandComplaintId': '178888'}}]}

Comment: can be there more than one object within `activities [...]` list?

Comment: yes exactly I need these columns: ActivityId,processId,demandComplaintSubject,demandComplaintDetailSubject and demandComplaintId

Comment: I'm not asking about columns, I'm asking could be there more than **one** object (with those columns) within activities [...] list?

Comment: Could you open this image in question ? [This image shows that the mongodb structure of one sample] i added screenshot of mongodb

Comment: "activities" : [ 
        {
            "activityId" : 
            "activityPageId" : 
            "prefix" : "E",
            "policyNo" : "2444234",
            "activityTypeId" : 
            "activityModeId" : 3,
            "createdDate" : ),
            "activityStatusId" : 2,
            "flowCenterInfo" : {
                "processId" : "178905",
                "demandComplaintSubject" : "Outsource Arama Talebi",
                "demandComplaintDetailSubject" : "Outsource Arama Talebi",
                "demandComplaintId" : "178905"
            }
        }
    ],

Comment: Could you help me about anaother topic ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650491/how-can-i-extract-mongodb-object-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650491/how-can-i-extract-mongodb-object-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `activities` key contains a list with a single dict, each field within `flowCenterInfo` key is marked with `fcinfo_`:

```
# sample list
l = [{'activities': [{'activityId': 'B83F36898FE444309757FBEB6DF0685D', 'flowCenterInfo': {'processId': '178888', 'demandComplaintSubject': 'İkna Görüşmesi', 'demandComplaintDetailSubject': 'Hayat Sigortadan Ayrılma', 'demandComplaintId': '178888'}}]},
     {'activities': [{'activityId': 'B83F36898FE444309757FBEB6DF0685D', 'flowCenterInfo': {'processId': '178888', 'demandComplaintSubject': 'İkna Görüşmesi', 'demandComplaintDetailSubject': 'Hayat Sigortadan Ayrılma', 'demandComplaintId': '178888'}}]},
     {'activities': [{'activityId': 'B83F36898FE444309757FBEB6DF0685D', 'flowCenterInfo': {'processId': '178888', 'demandComplaintSubject': 'İkna Görüşmesi', 'demandComplaintDetailSubject': 'Hayat Sigortadan Ayrılma', 'demandComplaintId': '178888'}}]}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([dict(**{'activityId': r['activities'][0]['activityId']}, \
                                     **dict(zip(map('fcinfo_{}'.format, r['activities'][0]['flowCenterInfo'].keys()), \
                                                r['activities'][0]['flowCenterInfo'].values()))) for r in l])
print(df)
```

---

```
                        activityId fcinfo_processId  ... fcinfo_demandComplaintDetailSubject fcinfo_demandComplaintId
0  B83F36898FE444309757FBEB6DF0685D           178888  ...            Hayat Sigortadan Ayrılma                   178888
1  B83F36898FE444309757FBEB6DF0685D           178888  ...            Hayat Sigortadan Ayrılma                   178888
2  B83F36898FE444309757FBEB6DF0685D           178888  ...            Hayat Sigortadan Ayrılma                   178888

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: you are genius RomanPerekhrest thank you so much bro it's worked very well ! But only 5 records it takes approximately three minutes from mongodb to build dataframe. Do you have any suggestions about this issue