# How can i extract MongoDB object to pandas Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, mongodb, dataframe

I want to extract from MongoDB collection only one object that i need.
There is an example about "manuelActivityInfo" object

```
x = list(
  coll
    .find(
      {
        "activities.manuelActivityInfo": {
          $exists: True,
        },
      },
      { "activities.activityId": 1, "activities.manuelActivityInfo": 1, _id: 0 }
    )
    .limit(5)
);


for row in x:
    print(row)
```

```
[
{ activityId: "0717FDE26F7B45A7A3B6A97BEAD6B00E" },
  { activityId: "348E5235D0DD4C83A1863B6CA69C557A" },
  { activityId: "ADA0E5CB36014B89A0ED9E7FC08EC48B" },
  { activityId: "FCD4E781050742E4A84F12A2E17D3D72" },
  {
    activityId: "FB744C79FFDF480C94069DF0F602C0AC",
    manuelActivityInfo: {
      manuelActivityTypeId: 1,
      manuelActivityTypeName: "Bilgi",
      manuelActivityMainSubjectId: 14,
      manuelActivityMainSubjectName: "Tazminat",
      manuelActivityDetailSubjectId: 60,
      manuelActivityDetailSubjectName: "Genel bilgi aktarımı",
    },
  },
  { activityId: "27B18A5C9ABA42A6B8AA0887C6916A25" },
]
```

I need only this part and i want to convert DataFrame
I want to take from collection only these columns

```
-ActivityId,
-manuelActivityTypeId,
-manuelActivityTypeName,
-manuelActivityMainSubjectId,
-manuelActivityDetailSubjectName,
-manuelActivityDetailSubjectId,
-manuelActivityDetailSubjectName
```

```
{'activityId': 'FB744C79FFDF480C94069DF0F602C0AC', 'manuelActivityInfo': {'manuelActivityTypeId': 1, 'manuelActivityTypeName': 'Bilgi', 'manuelActivityMainSubjectId': 14, 'manuelActivityMainSubjectName': 'Tazminat', 'manuelActivityDetailSubjectId': 60, 'manuelActivityDetailSubjectName': 'Genel bilgi aktarımı'}}
```

Also , i attached the Mongodb screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2FDs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

following your example,

you could do normal query like:

```py
x = list(
  coll
    .find(
      {
        "manuelActivityInfo": {
          $exists: true,
        },
      },
      {
        _id: 0,
        "activityId": 1,
        "manuelActivityInfo": 1
      }
    )
    .limit(1)
);

def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        yield (key)
        if type(value) is dict:
            yield from recursive_items(value)
#since we onli need 1 document
for i in recursive_items(x[0]):
    print(i)
```

[PYTHON-PLAYGROUND](https://www.online-python.com/3eiVOxEQug)
[MONGO-PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DGMDLaD05LY)

and if there are other fields within the `manuelActivityInfo`,

modify the projection part to be:

```
 _id: 0,
  activityId: 1,
  manuelActivityInfo: {
    manuelActivityTypeId: 1,
    manuelActivityTypeName: 1,
    manuelActivityMainSubjectId: 1,
    manuelActivityMainSubjectName: 1,
    manuelActivityDetailSubjectId: 1,
    manuelActivityDetailSubjectName: 1,
  },
```

Comment: x = list(
  coll
    .find(
      {
        "manuelActivityInfo": {
          '$exists': True,
        },
      },
      {
        "_id": 0,
        "activityId": 1,
        "manuelActivityInfo": 1
      }
    )
);

for row in x:
    print(row)   There is no row printing

Comment: x = list(
  coll
    .find(
      {
        "manuelActivityInfo": {
          '$exists': True,
        },
      },
      {
        "_id": 0,
        "activityId": 1,
        "manuelActivityInfo": {
    "manuelActivityTypeId": 1,
    "manuelActivityTypeName": 1,
    "manuelActivityMainSubjectId": 1,
    "manuelActivityMainSubjectName": 1,
    "manuelActivityDetailSubjectId": 1,
    "manuelActivityDetailSubjectName": 1,
  }
      }
    )
);

for row in x:
    print(row)   there is no rows return what is the wrong ?

Comment: @ErdalTutkuYILMAZ, sorry, i missunderstood before. i just updated.

Comment: i dont need activityIDs if has not ManuelActivity record there are lots of activityIds but I want to take data which has manuelactivityinfo

Comment: did  you try the phyton-playground

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyMongoArrow](https://mongo-arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to easily materialise MongoDB Query Result Sets into many other data formats such as Pandas DataFrame, NumPy Array, Apache Arrow Table.

It is built by MongoDB and it is getting popular among the data science community. This tool really simplifies this whole data movement part from one system to another in a really easy and quick fashion.